# Why is the class being exported in app.module.ts?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2 and working on creating applications in Angular 2 .

Can anybody please explain me what is the logic behind the statement "export class AppModule{}" in the app.module.ts file in Angular 2 application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Angular export empty class in app.modules.ts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316561/why-angular-export-empty-class-in-app-modules-ts)

Comment: In your main.ts you have to bootstrap a module. See the line platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)